# Show that an event is improbable for exponential families iff it's improbable for all absolutely continuous distributions

Tags: distributions, inference, nonparametric

Since all the exponential families are absolutely continuous, if part is trivial. However, I could not prove the only if part. My idea is to prove by contradiction, i.e. given an event $A$ such that $P(X\in A)=0$ for $X\sim F$, where $F$ is some distribution from the exponential families. We wish to show that $P(Y\in A)=0$ if $Y$ follows any absolutely continuous distribution. My idea is to assume the contrary and then create a random variable $Z$ from exponential family such that $P(Z\in A)=0$. My problem actually is that, I can not find a way to utilize the given information to get a contradiction. Please help.

Comment: One way is to show that every a.c. distribution is a member of at least one exponential family.

Comment: Maybe change the title to say *probabiity zero* white it now says *improbable*. As for the hint by @whuber, look into *exponential tilting* for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432688/exponential-family-definition-appears-vacuous/432766#432766

Comment: @whuber, do you want to say that the set of all absolutely continuous distributions is same as the set of all exponential families?!!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, Isn't improbable same as probability 0? Also, I couldn't understand exponential tilting from the link you've given. What do we do for uniform distribution?

Comment: That would be a confusing thing to maintain, because a family is a *set* of distributions.  What is at issue here mathematically is the question whether a point in a the plane (say) lies on any line.  Distributions are points in the space of all distributions and a distribution family is a curve (or higher dimensional manifold) in that space.  Exponential families are special kinds of curves (just like lines are special kinds of curves).