# What distributions are in the exponential family?

Tags: exponential-family

Are there any exponential family distributions other than wishart distribution, multivariate normal distribution, Dirichlet distribution, multinomial(or categorical) distribution, Conway-maxwel multinomial distribution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family

Answer (score 6):

When defining an exponential family ([Brown, 1987](https://amzn.to/3JYkns9))
$$f(x;\theta) = \dfrac{h(x) \exp\{B(\theta)^TR(x)\}}{\int_{\mathfrak X} h(x) \exp\{B(\theta)^TR(x)\}\,\text dx} \qquad x\in\mathfrak X,\theta\in\Theta$$
there is an infinity of choices both for $h(\cdot)$ (which roughly corresponds to the choice of the dominating measure) and for $R(\cdot)$.

Obviously, most of these families of distributions are not associated with a tradename, but they all are different.

Comment: For an interesting example without a tradename see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432688/exponential-family-definition-appears-vacuous/432766#432766